# Form Authentication Forcefully logout

Tags: asp.net

in web.config code is    
         section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

```
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>                             
    -->

    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies">                 
    </forms>
  </authentication>
```

whenever iam closing application and logging back user remains in and ask me to log out.. i want to make sure whenever application starts it should not be logged in previously..

this is web.config code..

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <!--
        The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
        of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
        during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
        it enables developers to configure html error pages 
        to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
        <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
        <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
    </customErrors>                             
    -->

    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies"> 

    </forms>
  </authentication>


  <authorization>
    <allow roles="Administrator,Attorney,Director of Operations,Office Manager,Paralegal,Partner,Processor,Salary Admin,Unit Manager"/>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>

  <pages>              
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

Login button code

```
 string [] arr = new string[10]; 
          bool bCheckUser;
            try
            {
                if ((txtUserName.Text == "") || (txtPassword.Text == ""))
                {
                    lblError.Visible = true;
                    lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    lblError.Text = "Enter UserName and Password";
                }
                else
                {
                    bCheckUser = Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);

                    arr = Roles.GetRolesForUser(txtUserName.Text);


                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, true);
                    FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);

                    if (bCheckUser == true)
                   {
                        lblError.Visible = false;
                        Response.Redirect("MainMenu.aspx");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblError.Visible = true;
                        lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                        lblError.Text = "You Username or Password is Invalid. Please try Again";
                    }

                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                lblError.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It looks like you are calling FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage regardless of whether Membership.ValidateUser returns true or false. That might have something to do with it. Is this code being called in the Page_Load of your login page?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing **true** to this method that is to create persistent cookies:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, true);
```

pass **false** instead and also move that inside of if block and remove that redirect if you don't want hard redirect:

```
if (bCheckUser == true)
{
       lblError.Visible = false;
        // Response.Redirect("MainMenu.aspx");
       FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, false);
}
```

Or use [SetAuthCookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk5762b.aspx) method like below:

```
if (bCheckUser == true)
{
       lblError.Visible = false;
       FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, false);
       Response.Redirect("MainMenu.aspx");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
It looks like you are calling FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage regardless of whether Membership.ValidateUser returns true or false.  That might have something to do with it.  Is this code being called in the Page_Load of your login page?

A couple of questions I have for you:

- Are you actually closing the browser
  and then reopening it, or just
  returning to your site after
  receiving an error in the same
  browser?
- Does your login page have a Remember
  Me setting?
- Have you restricted access to your
  webpages in your webconfig?

By default I think the webconfig leaves most pages open.  You'll need an authorization section to restrict access.

```
<authorization>
<deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Here's some links to check out as well:

- http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2004/02/02/effectiveformsauth.html
- http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb

Comment: Are you actually closing the browser and then reopening it, or just returning to your site after receiving an error in the same browser? 
yes iam doing that thing.. but still login name exists.. no iam not using login controls form doesnt have rememebr me setting. yes i have this is web.config <authorization> <deny users="?" /> </authorization>

Comment: Can you post some of your login code?  It's possible the forms authentication cookies are not expiring, though by default they should expire when the browser closes.